# React with net core backend. Can I use only amplify for CI/CD

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

I am setting up a react app with a fully serverless backend in AWS. Looking into aws amplify, it looks great and simplifying tons of things. I see it also can support your backend deployment, however, as to my knowledge so far, only if its nodejs/javascript.

As I have a requirement for using .net, I am confused if this can be achieved via amplify.
I.e my final goal is:

- frontend: react
- backend: .net lambdas connected to various queues and events
- (and this is the main confusion point) All being managed by amplify cli, creating and keeping in sync the cloud formation stack, connected to github, and serving as a CI/CD pipeline.

An alternative, as I see it would be to start 'backwards' from visual studio, defining all the backend lambdas needed and then adding a static frontetd.

But amplify CLI is so great, I was wondering if there is some way.
Any help I will appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After a week of RnD, and after finding out about [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html), chosen the following strategy:

stage 1

1) Use Amplify to provision needed Auth / AppSync / Dynamo services

2) Use VS Studio with [AWS SKD plugin](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) to provision needed Lambda / SQS / SNS / S3

stage 2

Create a CDK project, that will programmatically provision all infrastructure (in OPP manner), including CI/CD

Hope this helped someone :)